# How to install Eldy?

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install `eldy` (www.eldy.eu) on my computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and experienced problems.

I ran the following terminal command:

```
apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

and received an error that the software was not available.
Without it I could not install `eldy`.
There was a `.deb` available, but it could not be installed without `sun-java6-jre`.

Sources:

```
deb.vegans.it
eldy.eu
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, those packages haven't been updated since the 2008 so I'm not sure how much it will break if I use the equivalent packages to install it. So, this is an aventure:

First, install java:

```
sudo apt-get install java-7-jre
```

Why the 7? Well, because developers has been under cardiac arrest just to make sure that it's backwards compatible. Now create a folder:

```
mkdir ~/eldy && cd ~/eldy
```

Download and unpack the software:

```
wget http://download.eldy.net/eldy23.tar.gz
tar xf eldy23.tar.gz
```

Now you can execute eldy using `~/eldy/eldy/eldy.sh`.